# How to indent subsection in AMS TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, amsbook

I used AMS LaTeX template with gsm-l package to write my teacher's book.

The table of content that produced has the following form:

[image]

in which 1, 2, 3.... are sections and 3.1, 3.2, 4.1, 4.2,.... are the subsection.

I want to indent the subsection with respect to the section, like this (it's ok without dots, though):

[image]

Comment: For the future, it's best if you can provide a complete MWE as part of your question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The class `gsm-l` is based on `amsbook` and subsection entries in the ToC are typeset according to `\l@subsection` from `amsbook` with definition:

```
\def\l@subsection{\@tocline{2}{0pt}{1pc}{5pc}{}}
```

The third mandatory argument for `\@tocline` controls the indent for the entries; change `1pt` to `2.5pc` (or to the value that suits your needs):

```
\documentclass{gsm-l}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\makeatletter
\def\l@subsection{\@tocline{2}{0pt}{2.5pc}{5pc}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test chapter}
\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\section{Test section}
\subsection{Test subsection}
\subsection{Test subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Perhaps you might also want to change the fourth argument (controlling the hanging indentation for entries spanning more than one line), so perhaps

```
\def\l@subsection{\@tocline{2}{0pt}{2.5pc}{4pc}{}}
```

could also be a sensible redefinition.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, I use subsubsections in my writing and the currently accepted answer doesn't behave as one would like when there are additional indentations that need to be made.

If you're in the same boat as me, use this code to make subsubsections be indented beyond subsections in the ToC!

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\makeatletter
\def\l@subsection{\@tocline{2}{0pt}{2.5pc}{5pc}{}}
\def\l@subsubsection{\@tocline{2}{0pt}{5pc}{7.5pc}{}}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!