# Indenting subsections in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

[image]

Above on the left is what my current table of contents looks like in a paper I'm writing and I really wish I could indent subsections like I showed on the right side (which I admittedly just did in Paint by moving them all over 16px, which seems like the ideal amount).

Would anyone know how I could incorporate this into my paper?

Here is the smallest MWE I could manage:

```
\documentclass[10pt,article]{amsart}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section A}
\subsection{Subsection (16px Indent)}
\subsection{Subsection (16px Indent)}
\section{Section B}
\subsection{Subsection (16px Indent)}
\subsection{Subsection (16px Indent)}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @HenriMenke Although.. I don't need debugging help? I just want to learn how to indent subsections givin I'm using the normal old "\tablecontents".

Comment: You *do* need debugging help.  You say your code is not indenting subsections even though you want it to.  So post a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of maybe 20-40 lines of code starting from `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` which we can compile without any furhter dependencies and which exhibits the problem as described.

Comment: If you do not like the term “debugging”, replace it with “formatting” if you like.  In any case, we need a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @HenriMenke Ahh my mistake for misunderstanding -- I hope the edit is sufficient!

Comment: Do you have to use `amsart`?

Comment: @cfr Yes, it needs to still remain in my code, sorry if it's causing any inconvience.

Comment: Why? I ask because, if you've been told you must use it, then you probably shouldn't change the format of the ToC. If you haven't been told you must use it, then the question is why you're tied to it.

Comment: @cfr Oh! I guess this tied back into being new to LaTeX, I thought I had to use it for mathematical papers -- I've always used the same class in everything I've ever written. Is there an alternative I should switch to to make the ToC change and not affect the rest of the paper?

Comment: since you're using `amsart`, the easiest thing is to redefine the command that formats the subsection lines.  (this is a known flaw with the contents formatting in ams document classes.)  take a look at [How to indent subsection in AMS TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/177295/579)  (all ams document classes define the formatting levels of the toc in essentially the same way.)  i don't have access to a latex system right now, but will check in the morning.  if this works for you, then i can post a quick answer, or the question can be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: It is just that the standard classes indent subsections by default. For example, if you use `article`, the subsections are indented. You probably want to load the packages `amsmath` and `amssymb` in this case. You might also want `amsthm`. Generally, you don't have to use an AMS class in order to typeset maths, though you do generally need AMS packages for anything beyond the basics.

Comment: since this question has already been closed, and neither answer provides the answer i'd recommend, here that is:
`\makeatletter
%%\def\l@subsection{\@tocline{2}{0pt}{1pc}{5pc}{}}
\def\l@subsection{\@tocline{2}{0pt}{2pc}{6pc}{}}
\makeatother`
 the commented out definition is what's being replaced.  the second argument is the argument that specifies the indentation.

Comment: @barbarabeeton My goodness that's much simpler, thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be the following code can satisfy your need.

```
\documentclass[10pt,article]{amsart}

\makeatletter
\def\@tocline#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{\relax
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth % then omit
  \else
    \par \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace{#2}%
    \begingroup \hyphenpenalty\@M
    \@ifempty{#4}{%
      \@tempdima\csname r@tocindent\number#1\endcsname\relax
    }{%
      \@tempdima#4\relax
    }%
    \parindent\z@ \leftskip#3\relax \advance\leftskip\@tempdima\relax
    \rightskip\@pnumwidth plus4em \parfillskip-\@pnumwidth
    #5\leavevmode\hskip-\@tempdima
      \ifcase #1
       \or\or \hskip 1em \or \hskip 2em \else \hskip 3em \fi%
      #6\nobreak\relax
    \hfill\hbox to\@pnumwidth{\@tocpagenum{#7}}\par% <---- \dotfill -> \hfill
    \nobreak
    \endgroup
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section A}
\subsection{Subsection (16px Indent)}
\subsection{Subsection (16px Indent)}
\section{Section B}
\subsection{Subsection (16px Indent)}
\subsection{Subsection (16px Indent)}

\end{document}
```

The following is the PDF style.

[image]

Comment: I think the solution barbara linked would be (1) safer and (2) easier. @AndrewTawfeek

Comment: @cfr Had a bit of errors when I tried what was linked, maybe if I finagled things around I could get it to work! This seems to at least get things done for the time being -- I'm sadly in a rush due to a rough draft due soon and a lot of typing ahead!

Comment: @AndrewTawfeek The linked solution is also the one in barbara's comment.

Comment: @cfr yes, you are right. That solution is better.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use a standard class, indentation in the ToC is default. In this case, you probably want to load some extra packages to typeset mathematics. These are used by the AMS classes by default, by you have to load them specifically with a standard class.

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section A}
\subsection{Subsection (16px Indent)}
\subsection{Subsection (16px Indent)}
\section{Section B}
\subsection{Subsection (16px Indent)}
\subsection{Subsection (16px Indent)}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image: indents in ToC]

Whether this is the best option depends on your needs. Generally, other things being equal, pick a class which is as close to the layout you want for major document elements, so that you have less tweaking to do to customise it. Other things are not always equal. Some classes are badly coded and better avoided. But the default classes, the AMS classes, KOMA, Memoir etc. are all good bases to start from.

Comment: Thank you for the answer as well! After this semester comes to a finish I'll donate some honest time to genuinely learning LaTeX and understanding how to get around in different classes. Thank you for all the help!